# maths game for website not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having problems getting a game to work on my website. I had made the game using sublime text. the game is aimed at providing children with a fun way to learn and should display on a website to allow children to play the game and see their score. The game should start when the start button is clicked and should display a maths problem in the problem box and alert the user to input data using the keyboard.

html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="PrimaryLearning">
    <meta name="author" content="Jack McGowan">
    <title>Primary Learning | Subtraction</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="subtraction.css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div>
    <nav>
    <p>Primary Learning | Fun Maths Games</p>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lessons</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="addition.html">Addition</a></li>
        <li class="current"><a href="subtraction.html">Subtraction</a></li>
        <li><a href="multiplication.html">Multiplication</a></li>
       </ul>
        <li><a href="overview.html">Overview</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

<section>
    <div class='start-container slide-container'>
    <button id="start">START</button>
    <div id="timer-slide" class='timer slide-cover slid-up'>
    <p id="timer-label" class='label'>Timer</p>
    <p id="timer" class='main'></p>
    </div>
    </div>

   <div class='problem'>
    <p class='label'>PROBLEM</p>
    <p id="question" class='main'></p>
  </div>
  <div class='lights'>
    <div id='green-light' class='light'></div>
    <div id='red-light' class='light'></div>
  </div>
    <div class='score-container'>
       <p class='label'>SCORE</p>
      <p id="score" class='main'></p>
    </div>
 </section>

    <p class='label'>(Use Numbers on Keyboard)</p>

   </body>

 <footer>
    <p>Devenish College, Copyright copy 2019</p>
 <div>
  <p>Links to our social media accounts:<div><a href="www.twitter.com">Click here to find us on <strong>Twitter</strong></a></div><div><a href="www.facebook.com">Click here to Visit our <strong>Facebook</strong> page</a></div><div><a href="www.youtube.com">Click here to visit our <strong>Youtube</strong> channel</a></div></p>
 </div>
```

css

```
     *{
     margin-top: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }

   body{
     background-color: #CAEBF2;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-family: Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;
     line-height: 1.5;
     padding: 0;
   }

   nav{
     width: 100%;
     height: 60px;
     background-color: #A9A9A9;
     border-bottom: #FF3B3F 8px solid;  
   }

   nav p{
     font-family: verdana;
     color: #EFEFEF;
     font-size: 24px;
     line-height: 55px;
     float: left;
   }

   nav ul{
     float: left;
   }

   nav ul li{
     float: left;
     list-style: none;
     position: relative;
   }

   nav ul li a{
     display: block;
     font-family: verdana;
     color: #EFEFEF;
     font-size: 18px;
     padding: 22px 14px;
     text-decoration: none;
   }

   nav ul li ul{
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #FF3B3F;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
   }

   nav ul li:hover ul{
     display: block; 
   }

   nav ul li ul li{
     border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
   }

   nav ul li ul li a{
     padding: 12px 14px;
   }
   nav ul li ul li a:hover{
     background-color: #FF3B3F;
   }

   body{
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: column;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     text-align: center;
     min-height: 70vh;
     background: #1d1f20;
     color:white;
   }
   div{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     flex-flow: column nowrap;
   }

   section{
     border: 2px solid white;
   }
   section > div{
     margin: 5px;
     height: 4em;
     width: 10em;
     border-radius: 5px;

   }
   .score-container{
     background: #568bbd;
   }
   div.problem{
     background: #86b38a;
   }
   p.main{
     font-size: 1.4rem;
     margin: 5px;
   }
   p.label{
     font-size: 0.8rem;
     margin: 2px;
   }
   .lights{
     flex-flow: row nowrap;
   }
   .light{
     height: 20px;
     width: 20px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     margin: 5px;
   }
   .light::after {
     content: '';
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 2;

   }
   #green-light::after{
     background: #00ff00aa;
   }
   #red-light::after{
     background: #ff0000aa;
   }

   .white{
     background: white;
   }



   button{    
       border: 2px solid #42964c;
       background-color: #86b38a;
       color: white;
       border-radius: 10px;
       padding: 0.5em;
       font-size: 1.4rem;
       cursor: pointer;
       box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #42964c;
       transition-duration: 0.2s;
       text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #42964c;
       outline: 0;
     }

   button:hover{   
       transform: translateY(5px);
       box-shadow: 0 0 0 #42964c;
   }

   button:active{
     transform: scale(0.8);
   }

   .slide-container{
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
   }
   .slide-cover{
     position: absolute;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     transition-duration: 0.2s;
     transform: translateY(0);
   }
   .slid-up{
     transform: translateY(-120%);
   }

   #timer-slide{
     background: #d0782a;
   }
```

javascript

```
    ;(() => {
       var  totalScore, currentAnswer, timerCount, timerFunction, flashColorTimer, inPlay;
       const questionEl = document.getElementById('question');
       const scoreEl = document.getElementById('score');
       const redEl = document.getElementById('red-light');
       const greenEl = document.getElementById('green-light');
       const timerEl = document.getElementById('timer');
       const slideEl = document.getElementById('timer-slide');
       const timerLabelEl = document.getElementById('timer-label');
       const randInt = range => Math.random() * range | 0;
       const isNumber = val => !isNaN(val);
       function flashColor(colorName) {
           clearTimeout(flashColorTimer);
           redEl.style.background = colorName === "red" ? "white" : "black";
           greenEl.style.background = colorName === "green" ? "white" : "black";
           flashColorTimer = setTimeout(flashColor, 500);
       }
       const game = ({
           init() {
               inPlay = false;
               document.getElementById('start').addEventListener("click", this.start);
               document.addEventListener('keypress', event => game.answer = event.key);
               return this;
           },
           set score(value) { // abstract score now is how much is scored not total score
               if(value !== 0){
                   totalScore += value;
                   flashColor(value < 0 ? "red" : "green");
               } else { totalScore = 0 }
               scoreEl.textContent = totalScore;
               game.newQuestion();
           },
           set answer(value) {
               if (inPlay && currentAnswer !== null && isNumber(value)) {
                   game.score = (currentAnswer === Number(value)) ? 100 : -50;
               }
           },
           set timer(type) {
               const start = type === "start";
               timerCount = start ? 4 : 11;  // Add one as first tick is 0ms
               timerFunction = start ? game.begin : game.end;
               timerLabelEl.textContent = start ? "Starting in" : "Remaining";
               setTimeout(game.tick, 0);
           },
           tick() {
               timerCount -= 1;
               timerEl.textContent = timerCount;
               timerCount === 0 ?
                   timerFunction() :
                   setTimeout(game.tick, 1000);
           },
           start() {
               if (!inPlay) {
                   slideEl.classList.remove('slid-up');
                   currentAnswer = null;
                   game.timer = "start";
                   scoreEl.textContent = "0";
                   inPlay = true;
               }
           },
           begin() {
               game.score = 0;
               game.timer = "end";
           },
           end() {
               inPlay = false;
               questionEl.textContent = "";
               slideEl.classList.add('slid-up');
           },
           newQuestion() {
               currentAnswer = randInt(10);
               const r1 = randInt(10);
               const r2 = randInt(10);
               questionEl.textContent = `${r1}  + ${r2} - ${r1 + r2 - currentAnswer}`;
           },
       }).init();
   })();
```

'''

Comment: And what exactly is the problem?

Comment: when the start button is clicked on my website it should load my game and display the problems for the user to answer but when the start button is clicked currently nothing happens

Comment: Are you using any build tools, like webpack? If not, you're missing a script tag to load the JS in your HTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Comment: the only thing I'm using to make the game is sublime, apologies if im not very good at explaining as im very new to programming

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have no script tag in your html.  You need to have a script tag to call the JavaScript file.  Without this, your html file doesn't know to run the script.

```
<script src="filename.js"></script>
```

The best place to put this is usually at the bottom, but inside the body tag.  The html will run line by line.  So if you put the script tag in the head or near the top, then the js file cannot find elements of the page because they are not loaded yet.

Comment: put this in at the bottom and its working now thanks very much!

Comment: Great, glad I could help.  If it solved your problem, please mark as the solution.  Happy coding!